# EMGU in handled exception of initializing haarcascade.XML in C#

Tags: c#, portability, emgucv

I am doing a project on C# and emgu library.

My code works fine on my computer but when I try to run it on other computers it gives exception here:

```
  haar = new HaarCascade("detector_best.xml");
```

*exception is Unhandled type of exception in Sytem.Typeinitaialization occured in Emgu.CV.*

Kindly help me I am giving system environment path and working on Windows. also my file detector_best.xml is in my project's debug folder.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_EMGU_C_Sharp

System.TypeInitializationException:  Convertion from Image to Image is not supported by OpenCV 
Where * is the the relavent image depth or data type.

This error is thrown up in version 2.3.* onwards and is caused by the programs inability to access opencv_imgproc***.dll or opencv_core***.dll even though they are present in the output "bin" directory.

There are two solutions, adding them to the project and set there properties to copy always as they are the two key files. Or by replacing the current ones in the Bin folder with new copies can also solve the problem.

If both methods fail then there may be a problem with the build so download a new copy from SourceForge and try again.

I hope this article sets you on the right path, Thanks for reading.

Comment: I am sorry it worked when i re added  all libraries in project.

Answer (score 0):

It works when i added all .dll files from `C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.4.10.1940\bin` to `myproject\debug folder`also .dll from x86 and x64 from emgu Bin to my project debug like that,`C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.4.10.1940\bin\x86` to `myproject\debug\x86` and `C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.4.10.1940\bin\x64` to `myproject\debug\x64`